# Android onBackPressed wrong transition

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

On my KitKat emulator, I'm trying to simulate `onBackPressed()` when I click a button from a custom alert dialog but when I click the button, the wrong transition animation is shown. How can this problem be fixed so that when I click 'OK' the page I was on zooms out rather than the previous page zooming in?

```
public class AlertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_alert);

        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        ad.setCancelable(false);
        ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                final Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(AlertActivity.this);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        ad.show();
    }
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".notifications.AlertActivity"
        android:label="@string/alert"
        android:parentActivityName=".notifications.MenuActivity" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare it within the 'manifest.xml' file like this?

```
<activity
    android:name=".B"
    android:label="B" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.app_name.A" />
</activity>
```

Comment: No. I've just added my manifest code. Please adjust your code to improve your suggestion relating to my code.

Comment: Do I need to replace the `A` in `android:value="com.example.app_name.A"` with the name of my activity?

Comment: sorry i didn't see your manifest, yes you have to change B with ".notifications.AlertActivity" and A with "..notifications.MenuActivity"